# Weird python discrepancy between prompted input and declaring within program?

Tags: python

I have a python (v2.7.14) program to read in all the files within a directory, then plot certain data columns within those files all on one plot. I'm also labeling each respective line at the end with plt.text(), using the last x value and the 10th to last y value in each data set. This all works as long as I use a subroutine to prompt which directory to read, but if I manually insert it into the code (as in the commented out line seen below), it graphs without the text showing up. What's going on?

([graph with labels, running this code as is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVvj1.png))

([graph without, running with dire= './templates'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtIbq.png))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os
import sys


input_direct = raw_input

def get_dir(prompt):
    while True:
    direct_name = input_direct(prompt)
    direct_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), direct_name)
    if os.path.isdir(direct_name):
        return direct_name
    else:
        print("try again with a real directory")


def files_in_dir(dir_name, file_spec="*.dat"):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_name, file_spec))

def file_iter(files):
    for fname in files:
    with open(fname) as inf:
        yield fname, inf.read()


dire   = get_dir("enter directory: ")
#dire= './templates'
files = files_in_dir(dire, "*.dat")
files.sort(reverse=True)
content = [np.loadtxt(x, unpack=True) for x in files]
for i in range(len(files)):
    label=files[i][43:-4]
    plt.plot(content[i][0], (content[i][1]/np.sum(content[i][1])+float(i)/2000))
    plt.text(content[i][0][-1], (content[i][1][-10]/np.sum(content[i][1])+float(i)/2000),label)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You don't need the `./` to specify a directory in the current working path (just to force execution of an executable in the current path instead of searching PATH settings first in a *nix environment) - just using `templates` should do it... as the `os.path.join()` is no doubt removing the unnecessary fluff for you if you enter that from the prompt.

Comment: @JonClements, if I do just `templates` upon prompt the labels disappear then as well. I'm mostly confused because either way the file is still being read, it's just the labeling that breaks.